# Active directory delete description and office fields through powershell

Tags: powershell, active-directory, field-description

I have a list of users in active directory to which I have to remove the description and office fields. how can i do through poweshell? I try this but not work.

My code path is ok

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$Users = Import-csv C:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\test.csv
foreach($User in $Users){
Set-ADUser $User.SamAccountName -Description $User.NewDescription
}
```

my csv

```
SamAccountName;NewDescription;EmailAddress
xxxxxxxxxx;xxxxxxxxxxx;xxxxxxxxxxxxx@libero.it
```

Powershell answer

```
Set-ADUser : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Identity'. The argument is null. Provide a valid value for the 
argument, and then try running the command again.
At line:4 char:12
+ Set-ADUser $User.SamAccountName -Description $User.NewDescription
+            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Set-ADUser], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.SetADUs 
   er
```

Help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify your delimiter on your `import-csv` statement. The default is comma separated, so you can define it like so

`$Users = Import-csv C:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\test.csv -Delimiter ';'`

Without this, then it's importing as one single column instead of three.

See [Import-CSV](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-csv?view=powershell-7) for more.

Answer (score 0):

It might work?

$users = Import-Csv -Path C:\users1.csv

foreach ($user in $users) {
#Search in specified OU and Update existing attributes
Get-ADUser -Filter “SamAccountName -eq ‘$($user.samaccountname)'” -Properties * -SearchBase “cn=Users,DC=**********,DC=*****” |
Set-ADUser -Clear description, Office
}